# make a file undeletable

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have to test a message displayed by our application when it is not possible to delete a certain control file (used by our application; the file is stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeApplicationSubfolders). The tests need to be executed on some PCs from our client (which seem to have Windows 10 pro x64 ver1803, build 17134.345).

I've tried:

- using permissions (right-click the file > Security > Edit: Deny full control for user "Everyone"; or taken every user and ticked Deny for Full control), but every time the application manage to  delete the file, so I don't obtain the message.
- creating a Windows 10 user, ... but it seems this functionality was removed from our client's windows 10 image/iso. (I don't know what else is missing from the iso)
- opening the file with notepad (and keep it opened) and write something in it, without saving. This only "worked" once and I couldn't reproduce it. (I'm still suspecting there was something else which delayed or block the file deletion)

Are there better ways to block applications from deleting a file?

- I only need this for about 10 minutes (so something delaying the deletion might also work);
- It would be nice if no major OS changes would be required;

Comment: The "Notepad" approach is quite good but may be the wrong program. Start a program that keeps a handle to the file open (and the handle was created without `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag). As long as the program runs AFAIK even the SYSTEM user can't delete this file (user account with the highest privileges - higher than Administrator). AFAIR this behavior exists since Windows NT 3.x or even earlier.

Comment: Change ownership of the file security to SYSTEM, then inherit permissions, see if this stops the app from deleting it.

Comment: @Robert can you suggest me some other programs which would keep the handle to the file open? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So the method I am going to tell you is based on changing permissions for the files.

So what you did was adding a Group for Everyone and removing their permission for Modification. So the reason why it didn't work is because there are permissions set for other users to let them edit the files.

**How to do it**

So first go to the folder, Right Click and Properties>Security>Advanced.

So once you are here you first press Disable Inheritance and select "Convert inherited permissions to explicit permissions on this object"

Then you will see the various Groups and Users in the list.

So all you do is select each Administrator and User, press Edit and remove the permissions for Full control and Modify.

Then you tick the "Replace all child objects permissions with inheritable permissions..." and Press Apply.

**A few suggestions**

I would suggest to remove the write permissions from the Users too as they can just delete the contents of the file essentially deleting the file in a way.

Also if you want you may remove said permissions from the SYSTEM user too.

If you want to make it more tough for the users to delete the file do the following,
On top beside the owner press the Change button, then type SYSTEM into the empty box. Then press "Check Names" and press OK.

Then tick the "Replace owner on sub containers and objects" and press Apply.

After doing the following it would be impossible to delete the file and revert the changes unless the person knows how to do so.

**To revert the changes**

First if you have changed the owner to SYSTEM, change it back to yourself.

Then you just gotta remove all the Permission Entries and Press Enable Inheritance and Tick "Replace all child object...." and press apply.

It will go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you write "to display a message written by our application" I assume you are or have people in house that can develop applications.

The easiest way to make sure no one can actually delete the file, is by creating a new simple program with 2 buttons.

Button one opens that file for random access, but does not do anything else to the file. It just creates a file-lock.

Button two would close the file.

Now, you open your new program, press button one, and you should no longer be able to delete the file yourself using explorer, and as such, your other program won't be able to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the "Notepad" approach, this is easily achievable in Excel using VBA:

Put a macro "Private Sub Workbook_Open()" in the "This Workbook" area, and insert the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Open "path to your file" For Input As #1
    MsgBox ("Press OK to release file")
    Close #1
End Sub
```

When opening the .xlsm file, your file will be opened as input to the VBA macro.
It can not be (easily, as far as I tested) deleted.
To release the file, close Excel or press "OK" on the message box.

Of course this macro could also be placed in a normal module and be run using a button.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me, although you seem to imply that it didn't work
for you:

- Right-click the file and select *Properties*
- In Security tab, click *Edit*
- Click *Add*, enter `Everyone` and press *OK*
- Select `Everyone` and change *Full control* permission to Deny
- Click *Yes* to confirm
- Click *OK*

To undo:

- In the Security tab click *Edit*
- Select `Everyone`
- Click *Remove*.

Comment: That would do, provided the file hasn't already been opened by the application. This is very mysterious...

Comment: @Didier: If the file is already opened before the permissions were changed nothing can stop the delete.

Comment: My point exactly, @harrymc. On the other hand, if you deny permissions to everyone, that includes the application in question, so if it absolutely has to write onto this file, for some reason, it won't be able to do so. Another solution would be to create a working copy of the file in question, right before deletion by the application. This should be easier to set up, with PowerShell or any other scripting method, I think. You wrap the extinction of the application and the backing up the file in one script, and you're gold.